# No provider for FilterService on Kendo Grid in Custom Container when using angular 4

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, typescript1.4

I wrote a little wrapper, which wraps a Kendo Grid inside a custom control. It looks like this:

```
 <imx-grid [dataSource]="myTasks">
        <kendo-grid-column field="Task" title="Task">
                <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column>
                        versuch
                        <imx_stringFilter column="column" style="display:inline-block;" textField="Task" DisplayValue="versuch" valueField="Task">
                        </imx_stringFilter>
                    </ng-template>                        
        </kendo-grid-column>
     ...
```

The template for `imx-grid` only contains the kendo grid with some predefined values, that should be used on any grid.

Which should result in this image: [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjyay.png)

But instead I got a "*No provider for FilterService!*" exception. If I add an `providers["FilterService"]` statement to my `@Component(...)` definition, the exception doesn't occur, but the filtering done by my customFilter control doesn't apply at all, while the filtering done by the default filter is applied correctly.

For further information:
If I use my filter control on a non wrapped kendo-grid, the filtering works just fine, so I assume, that the problem isn't located within my filter control, but more likely inside my grid wrapper, which doesn't transfer the `FilterService` instance to the FilterControl correctly.

Does anybody know, if there is a workaround for this without redoing the whole filtering process?

Comment: I also have this problem did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: Did any of you found a solution for this?

Comment: I am facing same error. Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the service is not available through conventional means when your component is running outside of a kendo grid.

Marking the service as optional should allow your component to continue functioning.

```
  constructor(@Optional() filterService: FilterService) {
      super(filterService);
  }
```